# Custom Helper not available in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to create my custom `Helper` using extension methods but it is not available in views. This is the code.

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static IHtmlString LabelWithMark(this HtmlHelper helper, string content)
    {
        string htmlString = String.Format("<label><mark>{0}</mark></label>", content);
        return new HtmlString(htmlString);
    }

    #region ToCurrency
    public static string ToCurrency(this double number, string format = "{0, 6:C}")
    {
        return string.Format(format, number);
    }

    public static string ToCurrency(this double number, int numSpaces)
    {
        string format = string.Format("{0}, {1}{2}", "{0", numSpaces, ":C}");
        return string.Format(format, number);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

To test if I've been doing this all right, I also created two extension methods for built-in type `double`. When I define a new variable of `double`, the method is there:

```
double d = 123.45;
string s = d.ToCurrency(10);
```

I cannot make it work with `Html` helpers, though. In View, typing `@Html.` intellisync does not show the new helper.

EDIT:
I found that when I changed `IHtmlString` into `MvcHtmlString` and added `System.Web.Mvc;` namespace, I can see the new custom helper in Views:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelWithMark(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string content)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("<label><mark>{0}</mark></label>", content));
}
```

Comment: You should either add a `using` to your view, or add a namespace to web.config under Views folder

Comment: The above comment is more than enough. Nice.

Comment: I edited the question. I've changed the code slightly and added a new namespace. It's working now. Thanks.